# Doxygen XML output: <references> missing for global variable

Tags: doxygen

I am missing the

```
<references>
```

tags for global variables if the functions using them are defined in the same source file. They are there if I define the global variable in a different source file. Is there any known solution to this? The code is C for an embedded system.

Update:

I have narrowed it down to this: If the function references a member of the global struct, there will be only a reference to the typedef member, not a reference to the variable:

test.h

```
typedef struct
{
    int b;
} a_S;

extern a_S a;
```

test1.c

```
#include "test.h"

a_S a;

void UseA1(void)
{
    a_S *ptrA = &a; /* working, "UseA1" will reference "a" in the doxygen xml output */
}

void UseA2(void)
{
    a.b = 0;        /* not working, "UseA2" will NOT reference "a" in the doxygen xml output */
}
```

But only if the variable is defined in the same source file. If it is defined in another source file, there will be the reference to the variable as well as the reference to the typedef member:

test_data.c

```
#include "test.h"

a_S a;
```

test2.c

```
#include "test.h"

void UseA1(void)
{
    a_S *ptrA = &a; /* still working */
}

void UseA2(void)
{
    a.b = 0;        /* working too! */
}
```

Unfortunately this is not an option because of our existing coding standards... Is there any way around this?